# the node server can't access the object block(object-oriented javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, blockchain

I am trying to make a node server that can access each block object by its height, so here's the get route:

```
    // Enpoint to Get a Block by Height (GET Endpoint)
getBlockByHeight() {
    this.app.get("/block/height/:height", async (req, res) => {
        if(req.params.height) {
            const height = parseInt(req.params.height);
            let block = await this.blockchain.getBlockByHeight(height);
            if(block){
                return res.status(200).json(block);
            } else {
                return res.status(404).send("Block Not Found!");
            }
        } else {
            return res.status(404).send("Block Not Found! Review the Parameters!");
        }
        
    });
}
```

and here's the function to get the height of the block:

```
getBlockByHeight(height) {
        let self = this;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let block = self.chain.filter(p => p.height === height)[0];
            if(block){
                resolve(block);
            } else {
                resolve(null);
            }
        });
    }
```

and here's the block.js:

```
const SHA256 = require('crypto-js/sha256');
const hex2ascii = require('hex2ascii');

class Block {

    // Constructor - argument data will be the object containing the transaction data
    constructor(data){
        this.hash = null;                                           // Hash of the block
        this.height = 0;                                            // Block Height (consecutive number of each block)
        this.body = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(data)).toString('hex');   // Will contain the transactions stored in the block, by default it will encode the data
        this.time = 0;                                              // Timestamp for the Block creation
        this.previousBlockHash = null;                              // Reference to the previous Block Hash
    }
    

     
    validate() {
        let self = this;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // Save in auxiliary variable the current block hash
                        let currentHash=  self.hash                  
            // Recalculate the hash of the Block
         let  newHash =SHA256(JSON.stringify(self))
            // Comparing if the hashes changed
            if(newHash===currentHash){
resolve("Block is valid")

            }else{
            // Returning the Block is not valid
            reject("Block is not valid")
            }
            // Returning the Block is valid

        });
    }

    
    getBData() {
        let self = this;
        // Getting the encoded data saved in the Block
        // Decoding the data to retrieve the JSON representation of the object
        // Parse the data to an object to be retrieve.
let data=hex2ascii(self)
        // Resolve with the data if the object isn't the Genesis block
        let object=JSON.parse(data)
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
if(self.previousBlockHash==!null){
resolve(object)

        }else{reject()

    }
        

    });
}
}
    
module.exports.Block = Block;
```

I m getting no warnings in the console when I run the server, I attached a repo for the problem here:https://github.com/Mai9550/privateBlockchain2

Comment: Why is the second `getBlockByHeight()` returning a promise where there's nothing asynchronous in it?  Why doesn't it just return the value directly?  You seem to be using promises in lots of places for purely synchronous code.  That is an anti-pattern and just makes code more complicated than required.

Comment: And, what exactly is the problem you want help with?  Your question title is a generic, non-specific title that doesn't say what the problem is, what the observed behavior is, what the expected behavior is, what debugging you've done and what you're learned during that debugging.  This question needs a lot more info before anyone can do anything but try to guess what you might mean by this.

Comment: actually I need help with debugging it, everything just looks ok, where can I even start the debugging(in which method?)

Comment: First, you need to start and describe the problem.  We don't know where to look because we don't know what the problem is.

Comment: when I try to query the endpoint I get the error 'cannot get /block/0' and the route looks ok obviously so I think the problem is in block.js

Comment: In `getBlockByHeight()` in `BlockchainController.js`, you are configuring a route for `/block/height/:height`.  That will NOT handle a request for `/block/0` - it's expecting `/block/height/0`.  So, perhaps you're either requesting the wrong URL from the client or your server code is configuring the wrong route specification.

Comment: FYI, your coding style of putting each route in its own method on your BlockChainController makes your code very difficult to follow.  These route handlers need to all get initialized once at startup and never initialized again.  There's no reason to put each of these in a separate method that has to all be called individually.  Just list the related routes one after another and install them all in one code block.  Much easier to follow and maintain.

Comment: the issue got solved, the route was wrong, you can make that an answer and I set it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `getBlockByHeight()` in `BlockchainController.js`, you are configuring a route for

```
/block/height/:height
```

That will NOT handle a request for:

```
/block/0
```

The route code is expecting

```
/block/height/0
```

So, you're either requesting the wrong URL from the client or your server code is configuring the wrong route specification.